# Hotfolder in Go / wait for file to be written

Tags: go

I am trying to setup a directory as a hotfolder in Go. As soon as a file is finished written to that directory, a function should get called.

Now I came across https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify that seems to be a good building block for such a hotfolder.

My problem is that fsnotify emits lots of "file changed" events during the write but none when finished, so I assume its not possible that way to see if a process has finished writing files.

So I would think of "wait one second after the last 'file changed' event and then run my function. But I am unsure if this is the best way to deal with the problem and I am not really sure how to integrate this cleanly in the main event loop (from the given github page):

```
for {
    select {
    case ev := <-watcher.Event:
        log.Println("event:", ev)
    case err := <-watcher.Error:
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }
}
```

Any idea / advise?

Comment: Does your application need to be cross-platform? For instance, on a Linux-based system it's possible to spawn `inotifywatch` telling it to only monitor for the events of type `CLOSE_WRITE` and parse its output thus getting notified only of files that have been created/opened then written to then closed.

Comment: Well, I do need it cross plattform, but if my solution is not good enough, I'll come back to your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will wait until no event has been received for at least one second and then call `f()`.

```
for {
    timer := time.NewTimer(1*time.Second)

    select {
    case ev := <-watcher.Event:
        log.Println("event:", ev)
    case err := <-watcher.Error:
        log.Println("error:", err)
    case <-timer.C:
        f()
    }

    timer.Stop()
}
```

Comment: Good idea. I have now taken a two step approach: first I look for a "CREATE" event, then I jump to a loop like the one you gave to "wait" until written.

Comment: Very nice execution of this concept.  :thumbs-up: